# requestOracleData() Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to use `requestOracleData` as described in [Chainlink Documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) but all I get is a compile error

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
  --> contracts/libraries/GenericLargeResponse.sol:50:9:
   |
50 |         requestOracleData(req, fee);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

`ChainlinkClient` functions `requestOracleData` and `requestOracleDataFrom` have been changed to `sendChainlinkRequest` and `sendChainlinkRequestTo` respectively.